# Android Drawable with partial fill

Tags: android, android-drawable

I'd like to use a custom drawable to give my button rounded corners. However, I'd also like the bottom 1/4 of the rectangle to be filled with a particular color. Is this possible? How can I just fill the bottom quarter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible if you use a [Layer List](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) and define overlapping items. Here's an example...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="0dp" android:left="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:right="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corner android:radius="5"/>
            <solid android:color="#f000"/>
            <size android:width="200dp"
                android:height="30dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="0dp" android:left="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:right="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corner android:radius="5"/>
            <solid android:color="#0f0"/>
            <size android:width="50dp"
                android:height="30dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

You might need to play around with these values and adjust them to your needs

#### Edit

I don't think you can specify relative values, as in percentage. However, if these values differ based on screen sizes you can (and I recommend) moving this values to a dimension resource file as below...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="button_full_width">200dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="button_quarter_width">50dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="button_height">30dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

then specify these dimensions in your drawables as below...

```
...
<size android:width="@dimen/button_full_width"
                android:height="@dimen/button_height"/>
...
```

Now, to specify different values for different screen sizes you need to specify resource qualifiers that target different sizes by adding different "values" resource folders and placing the dimension files inside them with different values. The Android system will pick up and load the necessary dimensions at run time based on the device screen size...

```
res/
    values/
            dimens.xml
    values-small/
            dimens.xml
    values-normal/
            dimens.xml
    values-large/
            dimens.xml
    values-xlarge/
            dimens.xml
```

for more information [check out the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to specify the width/height relative to the button size instead of hard coding? Also, for the quarter that is colored, is it possible to specify the height as 1/4 of the height of the button, instead of hard coding values? My button size changes depending on screen size, so I'd rather not hard code anything. Thanks!!

Comment: Leo, also, is there any way to programmatically change the percent that is filled? Maybe go from 25, to 50, to 75, to 100?

Comment: Note, even if it means setting the values programmatically in onCreate, I'd be happy with that. So in that case, can I specify a shape drawable's height programmatically?

Comment: @WiseShepherd android natively support these kind of scenarios with very little effort in such a way that it's easy to maintain. Check my edit, I'm not too sure if relative values are supported though